# Change "FROM" mailadress in a function

Tags: php, wordpress

I installed a plugin called Message 2 Auther and its doing the job that i request. But, i dont want the "FROM" adress to be the Wordpress default mail, i want it to be from the user that wrote the message.

I've changed so that the subject is what i want it to be, but i dont know where to find the default mail.

Here is the code:

```
<?php defined('ABSPATH') or die('No script kiddies please!'); ?>
<?php

function m2a_getMessageBoxHTML() {
$messagebox = '<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"> 
</script><form class="form" method="post" action="' . 
esc_url(admin_url('admin-post.php')) . '"><input style="margin-bottom:15px;" 
type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">';
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    $messagebox .= '<input style="margin-bottom:15px;" type="email" 
name="user_email" placeholder="Email">';
}
$messagebox .= '<textarea style="margin-bottom:15px;" name="message" 
placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="m2a_new_message" 
/>
                <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="' . get_the_ID() 
. '" />';
$options    = get_option('m2a_setting');
if ($options['googlecaptcha'] && $options['googlecaptchapublickey']) {
    $messagebox .= '<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="' . 
$options['googlecaptchapublickey'] . '"></div>';
}
$messagebox .= '<input type="submit" class="button btn" 
name="submit_message" value="submit" />
            </form>';
return $messagebox;
}

function m2a_getPopupHTML() {
add_thickbox();
$messagebox = '<div id = "my-content-id" style = "display:none;">
<form class = "form" method = "post" action = "' . esc_url(admin_url('admin- 
post.php')) . '" style = "text-align:center;">';
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    $messagebox .= '<p class="mail_rubrik">Mail:</p><input     
class="ruta_rubrik" style = "margin-bottom:15px;" type = "email" name = 
"user_email" placeholder = ""><br/><br/>';
}
$messagebox .= '<p class="meddelande_text">Meddelande:</p><textarea 
class="meddelande_ruta" style = "margin-bottom:15px;" name = "message" 
placeholder = "" rows = "5"></textarea>
<input type = "hidden" name = "action" value = "m2a_new_message" />
<input type = "hidden" name = "post_id" value = "' . get_the_ID() . '" />';
$options    = get_option('m2a_setting');
if ($options['googlecaptcha']) {
    $messagebox .= '<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="' . 
$options['googlecaptchapublickey'] . '"></div>';
}
$messagebox .= '<br/><br/><input type = "submit" class = "button btn" name = 
"submit_message" value = "Skicka" />
</form></div>
<a href = "#TB_inline?width=auto&height=auto&inlineId=my-content-id" class = 
"thickbox btn button">Skicka ett meddelande</a>';
return $messagebox;
}

function m2a_sendemail($to, $subject, $message, $usermail = 0, $post_id) {
$post_title = get_the_title($post_id);
$site_name  = get_bloginfo('url');
if ($type == 'author') {
    $message = "Du har ett nytt meddelande från {$usermail}<br/>Meddelande: 
{$message} </a>";
} else {
    $message = "Du har ett nytt meddelande från {$usermail}<br/>Meddelande: 
{$message}<br/></a>";
}
$subject = "Nytt meddelande på 4 Happy Pets";
wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, array('Content-Type: text/html; 
charset=UTF-8'));
}

function m2a_aftercontent() {
$m2a_setting = get_option('m2a_setting');
if (isset($m2a_setting['aftercontent']) && $m2a_setting['aftercontent'] == 
1) {
    if ((!isset($m2a_setting['nonuser'])) || ($m2a_setting['nonuser'] == 1 
&& is_user_logged_in())) {

        function m2a_messagebox($content) {
            $m2a_setting = get_option('m2a_setting');
            if (is_single()) {
                if ($m2a_setting['showas'] == 'messagebox')
                    return $content . m2a_getMessageBoxHTML();
                else
                    return $content . m2a_getPopupHTML();
            }
        }

        add_filter('the_content', 'm2a_messagebox');
    }
}
}

add_action('init', 'm2a_aftercontent');


/*
 * Saving Data to database
 */

function m2a_message_db_store() {
global $wpdb;
// global $post;
$postid   = $_REQUEST['post_id'];
$authorid = get_post_field('post_author', $postid);
$subject  = $_REQUEST['subject'];
$message  = $_REQUEST['message'];
$options  = get_option('m2a_setting');
if ($options['googlecaptcha']) {
    $captcha = $_REQUEST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $response = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$options['googlecaptchasecretkey']."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), true);
    if ($response['success'] == false) {
        wp_safe_redirect(wp_get_referer());
    }
}

    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        $userid   = $_REQUEST['user_email'];
        $usermail = $userid;
    } else {
        $userid   = get_current_user_id();
        $usermail = get_userdata($userid)->user_email;
    }
    $tableName = $wpdb->prefix . 'm2a_message';
    $wpdb->insert($tableName, array('user_id' => $userid, 'author_id' => 
 $authorid, 'post_id' => $postid, 'subject' => $subject, 'message' => 
 $message));
    $options   = get_option('m2a_setting');
    if (isset($options['emailtoauthor']) && $options['emailtoauthor'] == 1) 
 {
        $to = get_userdata($authorid)->user_email;
        m2a_sendemail($to, $subject, $message, $usermail, $postid);
    }
    if (isset($options['emailtouser']) && $options['emailtouser'] == 1) {
        m2a_sendemail($usermail, $subject, $message, 0, $postid);
    }
    wp_safe_redirect(wp_get_referer());
}

add_action('admin_post_nopriv_m2a_new_message', 'm2a_message_db_store');
add_action('admin_post_m2a_new_message', 'm2a_message_db_store');

// Create shortcode
function messagebox($atts = array()) {
    $a    = get_option('m2a_setting');
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
       'style' => 'default',
          ), $atts, 'message2author');
    if ((!isset($a['nonuser'])) || ($a['nonuser'] == 1 && 
is_user_logged_in())) {
        if ($atts['style'] == 'messagebox') {
            return m2a_getMessageBoxHTML();
        } elseif ($atts['style'] == 'popup') {
            return m2a_getPopupHTML();
        } elseif ($atts['style'] == 'default') {
            if ($a['showas'] == 'messagebox') {
                return m2a_getMessageBoxHTML();
            } elseif ($a['showas'] == 'popup') {
                return m2a_getPopupHTML();
            }
        }
    }
}

add_shortcode('message2author', 'messagebox');
?>
```

Comment: after a quick sneak into the [source code](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/message-to-author/trunk/functions/functions.php) it looks like this plugin uses a wordpress funtion to send the mail:  `wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'));` - which makes it not easy (even possible?)  to change the 'from'

Comment: maybe there's a wordpress setting somewhere??

Comment: https://firstsiteguide.com/change-default-wordpress-email/

Comment: allright, so its not possible for me just to use a mail adress from the form thats being submitted?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/160017/how-to-set-from-address-according-to-the-form-input-email-address-for-wp-mail

Comment: I used the $header and it works if the user is not logged in. Any suggestions to what to exchange when the user is logged in?

function m2a_sendemail($to, $subject, $message, $usermail = 0, $post_id) {
    $post_title = get_the_title($post_id);
    $site_name  = get_bloginfo('url');
 if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
$headers = array('From: '.$_POST['user_email'].' <'.$_POST['user_email'].'>');
 }